# Is there a way to bring down the Dark Brotherhood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to bring down the Dark Brotherhood in its own quest-line? If so, how would I start it?

I want to play the game from a completionist's approach trying to finish *all* the quests, but I don't necessarily want to be a murderer. I am a thief already for the lack of choice concerning the Thieves Guild in Riften, so I hope the game doesn't force me to become a murderer as well.

Comment: You can fail the first quest related to the Thieves Guild by leaving the area (entering a building or leaving Riften). You are then invited to (but not forced to enter and join) the Guild's hideout should you change your mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I stop those assassins that are trying to kill me?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40093/how-can-i-stop-those-assassins-that-are-trying-to-kill-me)

Comment: @alexanderpas If the other question was renamed into the actual question found in text, namely "How do I destroy the Dark Brotherhood?", I would agree that mine is a duplicate. As it stands now it is not clear at first hint and is not necessarily found. I didn't when looking for the answer before asking.

Comment: I agree, done ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Do the first quest where you kill the head of the orphanage. Get a note from a courier and then go to sleep. You will wake up with the leader of the dark brotherhood in the room who tells you to do something. Kill her instead; it starts you on a quest to eradicate the dark brotherhood entirely.

Comment: Killing Astrid is no easy task though.

Answer (score 5):

You can kill the lady in the Abandoned Shack (Astrid) when you wake up. After that you need to go and talk to a town guard who sends you to go kill the remaining dark brotherhood memebers. I think he sends some other guards with you.

> This kills off the last remaining Dark Brotherhood people besides the jested, Cicero.