# Has anyone encountered a dark brotherhood assassin?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are assassins coming after me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/why-are-assassins-coming-after-me)

I want to know if it's possible to find out who did the black sacrament to have me killed.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a note on the assassin that mentions who is paying.  Basically, you killed someone with at least on living relative, who now wants you dead.